# CakePHP - layout and view

Tags: cakephp, layout, view

I have some problem with layout in CakePHP. I want have one things whick will be in all pages - login form - but it is in view... How Can I add view(/Users/login.ctp) to layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have some HTML that is repeated among several different views you can use an element.

Create a .ctp file in the "/app/view/Elements" folder. For example, "/app/view/Elements/loginform.ctp".

In that file you would create your login form. Everything available in your view is available in this file (for example the HTML Helper).

To insert this element just do `echo $this->element('loginform');`  . You can do this both in your view file, or in your layout file.

Comment: More about [CakePHP Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements).

Comment: Ok - I know but f.e. : 

I have Controler -> Users(contains login,register etc. ) and the View -> View/Users/login.ctp(where is login form)

Now in layout I wont have login.ctp(View/Users/login.ctp) 

I try `$this->extend('/Common/view');` but the layout disappear.

How to do this?

Comment: Lets see if I'm understanding you. CakePHP will automatically insert the view in your layout when you access `/users/login` . If you want to insert the login form in other views, or in all views, you should create an element. Then in `Views/Users/login.ctp` you can include this element as well.